# not able to print in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using RMarkdown and want to print full table in a knitted pdf. When I run following code, the pdf is blank. How do I do this?

````
library(data.table)
mydat <- fread('http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~lynn/iid/wolf.river.dat')
mydata<-as.data.frame(mydat)
#mydata<-as.data.table(mydat)
```
````

..

```
`r head(mydata)`
```

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce. What error do you get?

Comment: Try `{r} head(mydata)`

Comment: @NelsonGon - attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this line `r head(mydata)` with

````
```{r}
head(mydata)```
````

Comment: see above screenshot

Comment: Try as I suggested here. You seem to have wanted to show data. Calling `r mydata` will not work(although I'm not exactly sure why).

Comment: yeah, thanks. Hope somebody else in community have answer to that